# Filesharing and anonimity

Tags: tails

I am looking for a mainstream filesharing service that I can use with no concern about my location and connection details being leaked and logged.

I don't care about data encryption or the big G or Dropbox snooping around my files: the files will be carefully anonymized, and they will be published for free access to anyone.

My only concern is: I do not want a later investigation by a potentially very determined adversary to ask the activity log to, say, Dropbox, and Dropbox revealing my true exact location, IP, ISP etc, because of TAILS leaking some valuable information while I was using the service.

My fear is about the things I do not really understand: I know Java can deanonimyze you, and Dropbox (or any other filesharing website, AFAIK) won't work if i disable Java on TOR browser selecting the "Safest" security preferences.

I know that Onionshare would be just the perfect fit, but unluckily I need a mainstream platform that anybody can access, use and interact with, and last but foremost without raising the suspicion I want to remain anonymous.

Any service that is advertised as built for anonimity would just not be the thing for me.

Do you have any recommendation?

The recommendation can also be "Steer clear of filesharing and use good old emails". That would be a mess, but anonimity can't be easy as we all know.

About my previous research:

I have to rule out Google Drive simply because using it with TAILS is a pain in the arse, with one captcha after the other.

Dropbox on the other hand seems to be absolutely OK with TAILS users.

Seafile (added benefit: it's in China, possibly not a really cooperative country in case of a later investigation by western authorities).

Spideroak, I haven' investigated yet.

Tresorit, same as above.

Comment: UPDATE: I just found out the existence of self hosted filesharing services. In this case I may go for a hosting company that guarantees me a good level of privacy, or even a nolog policy. The same log problem remains with the filesharing service though: even if the server is "mine", the software can still log any activity I perform on it, hence precious location, DNS and IP data that I want to keep safe.

Comment: UPDATE: is a RaspberryPi router in between my TAILS laptop and the hotspot connection a further layer of security that would prevent unwanted DNS leaks?